# Keyboard displaying wrong characters

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and when I tried to sign in to my gmail account I realised that when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> it outputs `"` instead of `@`. Every other <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0–9</kbd> combo works just fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your keyboard layout set to and what is your keyboard layout supposed to be?

Comment: Check your language preferences  (english uk, english us etc)

Comment: Just checked out the input sources in the settings 1)English UK 2)English US . I was using the UK variant when this issue occured.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is how the English UK keyboard is supposed to work. When I switch to English US everything works just fine!